# How does Python mock class works?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-mock

This is a example I have a class :

engine/a.py

```
from thirdlib import TaskClient
class TaskWorker(object):
    def __init__(self):     
          self.task_client = TaskClient(xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx)

    def some_task(id, app):
        tasks = self.task_client.query(1,2,3,4)
        print "tasks: " tasks
        for task in tasks:
           do_something()
```

then I want to test it:

```
class ImporterTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client_patcher = patch('engine.a.TMClient', autospec=True)
        self.client_mocked = self.client_patcher.start()
        self.worker = TaskWorker()

def tearDown(self):
    self.client_patcher.stop()

def test_task_return_empty(self):
    self.client_mocked.query.return_value = []
    value = self.worker.some_task(1, 'notcare')
    #self.assertFalse(value)
    #print self.client_mocked.mock_calls
    self.client_mocked.query.assert_called_with(1,2,3,4)
```

This test will failed with query.assert_called_with,

```
 Tasks: <MagicMock name='TMClient().query()' id='139779549447120'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 925, in assert_called_with
  raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
```

AssertionError: Expected call: query(1,2,3,4)
Not called

the print expected "Tasks: []"  but not , as the assert_called_with is failed also

Comment: The task_client in your TaskWorker is still a real object not the mocked one

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana  actually not, self. client_mocked  and self.worker.client  is the same Class, not same instance.  Have resolved it

Comment: patch is created for engine.a.TMClient class but task_client is of type TaskClient